# Set<String> treating [1.0,1] as different values

Tags: java, set

I am having a code sequence like this which is part of an Accuracy checking of a Data mining algorithm.

ie A trained data gets compared against some predicted values from my algorithm, and accuracy checking is done comparing both class labels.

say my values are `[No,No],[No,Yes],[1.0,1],[1,1],[1,0]` which are class labels
I am trying to compare the accuracy of my predicted data

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (Text val : values) {
        set.add(val.toString());
    }
    int count = set.size();
    if(count == 1){
        System.out.println("Correct class label");
        corClass++;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("InCorrect class label");
    }
```

---

```
[No,No]: Correct class label
[No,Yes]: InCorrect class label 
[1.0,1]: InCorrect class label
[1,1]: Correct class label
[1,0]:InCorrect class label
```

For me **[1.0,1]** this is falling into **incorrect classlabel**.

`Set<String>` set is treating [1.0,1] as different eventough they are equal but double and integer.

How to fix a workaround.

Please suggest

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe because `"1.0" != "1"`? It sounds like you'll want to convert all numbers to integers before calling `toString()`

Comment: `Set<String>`means that the value of the set is a `String`. And the String `1.0` is not equals the String `1`.

Comment: @Jon: Yes but I am doubtfull as the incoming value it self is string format.values is Text ~String

Comment: Why do you say `1.0` is a double? Do you have some rule that constrains what types this can hold? If so, where's the code that implements this rule?

Comment: @SreeVeni - What type of values can be held by the set?. It makes little sense to convert all values to integers if you have to compare `1.5` and `1.1` somewhere in your program.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have rules that your code doesn't respect. You say `1.0` is a "double". Is there a rule that determines under which conditions the code is a double? For example, is "1e10" a double -- 1 x 10^10? Or is it a string like "yes" presumably is?

`1.0` and `1` are different strings. If you have some comparison rule that makes these two things identical, you'll have to implement it somewhere -- it won't happen by magic. It's not clear from your question precisely what the rule is, but whatever it is, implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not storing a set of strictly strings, you're storing a set of both strings and integers.  You don't know which one you're going to put in next, but you don't necessarily care about that; you're just leveraging the set properties for your use case.

What you can do instead of just create a set that stores most any object in it.

```
Set<?> set = new HashSet<>();
for (Text val : values) {
    try {
        set.add(Double.valueOf(val.toString()).intValue());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        set.add(val.toString());
    }
}
```

It's not an attractive thing to do when we're talking about using exceptions as control flow, but this will get you past your immediate pain.

Comment: This way don't you lose the type safety of the Set? It's still the best answer so far, but it bothers me a little.

Comment: Basically, everything in there is regarded as `Object`, but the deduplication properties of the set are preserved.  If you don't want to get anything out of the set, this is fine.  If you *do*, you're going to want to look into a custom type instead.

Comment: Yep, exactly. More details from OP would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are using a set of strings to store your data. Since it is a set of Strings, the set will allow any elements that are unequal strings. Wouldn't it be confusing if you were writing a different application, where you really needed string equality, if `"1".equals("1.000")==true`?

In this case, I think it would be better not to use a set at all...

This function should work properly for any number or string based equality:

```
public boolean stringOrDoubleEqual(String a,String b){
    try{
       //Change the 0.001 to the acceptable error for your application.
       return Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(a)-Double.parseDouble(b))<0.001;
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
       return a.equals(b);
    }
}
```

I'm sure the rest should come naturally, if this fits your use case :)

Comment: Do not rely on equals for primitive doubles.  Ever.

Comment: `parseDouble` gives you back a primitive double.  Even if you were using `Double`, don't do that either; `equals` has a very similar assumption with two special cases.

Comment: @Makoto If you look carefully, you'll see that the double's produced by parse double are compared with == then returned. The only case using `equals` is if the parsing fails. Then we compare the strings a and b with `.equals`

Comment: Yes.  I can see that you're comparing primitive doubles with `==`.  [**That's what I take umbrage with.**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Makoto Oh, I see. I thought you meant literally `equals`. I probably should've checked your rep before back sassing you though. If you want to suggest an edit feel free :)